# Is it there a full movie editing software that I can get that has a chroma keyer?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I am starting to get into the world of film making/editing.

I tried to use iMovie, but it just doesn't have the functionality that I need.

Is there a good movie editing software that has a chroma keyer for free?

Comment: chroma-key I have heard of - chroma-keyer? - is this what you are after? http://www.openshotvideo.com/2009/10/screencast-of-chroma-key-effect.html

Comment: I didn't ask for just a chroma keyer, I wanted the best full movie editing software that I can get that has a chroma keyer... someone edited the whole post...

Comment: "best movie editor" is a debating type question and will be subject to closure as per the FAQ. Is the openshot link above the functionality you are after?

Comment: According to the website it does, but I am still downloading it...

Answer (score 0):

## **Cinelerra**

**Cinelerra** is a Sophisticated Movie Editor. It is having all most all the features found in Commercially available popular video editors

**It is Having Chroma Key**.

You can Install Cinelerra with ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
```

In its **Resource Window > Video Effects > Chroma Key** you can get chroma key.

You need to Drag and Drop this Icon to the Compositor Window.

Then, Chroma key Track will appear in Timeline

There is a small Button in this track. By click in it, You can get the Settings window for Chroma Key.

[image]

[image]